# Impala how to select only numeric and special characters, ignore any alphabet?

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I have a dataset that's really messy and I want to find the missing values. These have been denoted in a mix of ways such as -1, *, --, ##### etc.

I want to remove any rows that have alphabet and just show rows with numbers, special characters, or a combo of both, group them and display a count of each value.

I've been trying it like this:

```
select firstname, count(*) from dataset 
where firstname not like '%[a-zA-Z]%' 
group by firstname
```

This just seems to be returning all results including alphabet.

I'm not used to working in impala so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: `regexp_like(firstname , '[^a-zA-Z]') `

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [REGEXP](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build3x/html/topics/impala_operators.html#regexp) operator in impala

```
select firstname, count(*) as count
from dataset
where firstname REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]'
group by firstname;
```